# how to control data while returning to react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a part for perfect money's payment as follow:
I'll send amount & data to perfect money and It will be returned to react from perfect money's site.
There's this error while returning from perfect money:.
Cannot POST /
The data that is coming from perfect money to react ,is using method post.what should I do?

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory}>
<Switch>
<Route exact path='/' component={()=><Home />} />
</Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: can I handle it just by react ,or not?

Answer (score 0):

Change callback url for "cancel" to `yoursite.com/?action=cancel` on perfect money's site. Notice the `action=cancel` part. Now you need to check it in your React app like this:

**React Router v3**

With React Router v3, you can get query-string from `this.props.location.search` (?action=cancel). For example, with `let params = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)`, would give `{ action : 'cancel'}`

**React Router v4**

With React Router v4, the `this.props.location.query` does not exist anymore. You need to use **`this.props.location.search`** instead and parse the query parameters either by yourself or using an existing package such as [`query-string`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string).

**Example**

Here is a minimal example using React Router v4 and the `query-string` library.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import queryString from 'query-string';

// ...

render(){
    let params = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
    // use params
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I send an amount and gateway data to perfect money's site by using method post for my online payment gateway. When user is in perfect money's site and for example he click on cancel button and return to my site from perfect money's site.There's no api for this and It's returning to my website only by Cancel button in perfect money's site and React app's link that I gave to.Whenever I send data to their site ,there isn't any api.There is several steps for payment and I can't do it just by api directly.

Comment: Yes, "cancel" is one of the reactions. That's  possible for it to send amount completely and after that redirect to my site. I should receive data by react and send it to node js until that my user's acount will charge  in my site automatically.